# setting chrome ( on mac ) so that when multiple tabs are open, it asks me whether it should close

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Sometimes I accidentally hit the close button and while multiple tabs are open, it closes. On my other computer, it asks me.

How do I get chrome to give me that choice again?

Comment: `Chrome > Warn Before Quitting (⌘Q)`. Kind of stupid for them to put it outside the actual preferences, but what can you do.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off-topic here. This is a site for programming questions. Voted to migrate this question to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this feature doesn't exist, but there's a plugin that does this.

See: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lnpifgapnmpninomacbhdlconlpikdai

Comment: Thank you for your reply... But, I wouldn't go that route. That plugin is able to access all web sites and all data. You really got to trust that plug in to go down that route. There must be a built-in option.